# Remove strings that are sub-strings of others

Tags: text, substring

Given a set of strings, I need to remove every string that is a sub-string of another in the set. The sub-string could occur in any position. I expect that at least 50% of strings will be sub-strings of others. My strings are n-grams from large natural language corpora.

For example, given ("the big car", "big car", "at the big car", "buy a big car", "buy a big", "buy a big house") then the results should be ("at the big car", "buy a big car", "buy a big house"); ordering the output is not important.

Because my set has 100,000's of strings then brute force testing each string against all others is not an option.

Does anyone know a standard solution to this problem?

Or, can anyone add to some thoughts I've had:

- if I sort the strings first it should be easier to pick off sub-strings at the start of strings (and ends of strings with reverse sort)? Still need to deal with sub-strings in other places.
- use a tree structure? something like the following? (i) add START and END tokens to each string; (ii) first node in tree is START; (iii) string "big car" --> new branch START-big-car-END, but then when "the big car" is added the branch becomes START-the-big-car-END; (iv) once all strings inserted then read off all paths from START to ENDs. Not sure about this given a potentially large set of words (at least 1000's). Also, problem of same word occurring more than once in a sentence.
- could I add some kind of memory to the brute force, such that the next string processed can be first compared to a set of previously deleted strings?

Comment: I guess you want to have an algorithm ? if you wanna an example code to remove substring in specific programming language like c#. I think you could use lambda expression and its performance's not slow

Comment: [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) may be good choice

Answer (score 0):

I am using the lapply function in R to achieve this:

```
calc <- function(e, df){
    i <- 1
    while (!(grepl(e[[1]],df[i,1], fixed=TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)) & i <=nrow(df)){

        i <- i + 1

    }       
    return (df[i,])
}


    reduced  <- lapply(input_df[,1], calc, df=input_df)
    output_df <- do.call(rbind,reduced)
```

The performance is good ever on large datasets, but not on very large datasets.

**Note:** I sort the input_df by length (DESC) to get the best performance